# Angular three play gltf File is is not play animation

Tags: angular, three.js

I want to use a nice 3D animation at my page. I use angular and three.js with angular-three package.

All works good, but my gltf file has a lot of animations inside which not playing. I read a lot of other posts here, but nothing worked for me. This is my code:

```
  private createScene() {

     //* Scene
     this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
     this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff)

     this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/3d/walle/scene.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
     let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
     let action = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] );
     var animations = gltf.animations;

     animations.forEach(animation => {
         mixer.clipAction(animation).play();
         //console.log("foreach ",animation.tracks);
     });
```